# Regex to match html element pair

Tags: regex

I have the following regex to find matched tags:

```
<(\w+)(\s*[^>]*)>[^<]+?<\/\1\s*>
```

It is pretty basic but basically I'm trying to capture the tag (such as `em`) and make sure the item is enclosed with that same tag. Here are some examples: https://regex101.com/r/1R1qzh/1. However, as you can see, it also matches something like this:

```
<h5>tommy</h>
```

Why is this so? What would be the correct regex for this simplified html element match? The inputs to test would be:

```
<h5 size="12">tommy</h>   # no
<h5>tommy</h5>            # yes
<h5 >tommy</h5>           # yes
<h5 size="12" >tommy</h5> # yes
<h5  >tommy</h5>          # yes
```

Comment: The reason yours matches the first string is because `(\s*[^>]*)` is absorbing the `5`. Change that to an alternation enforcing a space before attributes and it works https://regex101.com/r/1R1qzh/5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You generally should not be using regex to parse/validate HTML.  If you did want to match only single-level correctly formed tags, you may use:

```
<([^\s>]+)(?:\s+[^>]*)*>[^<]+</\1\s*>
```

### Demo

Comment: that only matches 1/4 of the matches from the demo I have though. For example, `<h5  >tommy</h5>` doesn't match.

Comment: --why does the first one in the demo capture `h` instead of `h5` for the first example?